# Subtyping or Generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, subtyping

This is a Java Assignment question, possibly concerning sub-typing and generics. I have a class that extends `ArrayList` called Rows

```
public class Rows extends ArrayList<List<Thing>> implements List<List<Thing>>{}
```

I need to return it in another class which has a method that returns a `List<List<Thing>>`, thus I need to do this in order to get the desired return type:

```
private List<List<Thing>> list;

public List<List<Thing>> rows() {
    Rows r = (Rows) list;// But this cast does not work at runtime
    return (List<List<Thing>>) r;
}
```

The error Eclipse returns is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList` cannot be cast to package.Rows. I am quite confused as my Rows class extends `ArrayList` and I thought that it should be able to be cast to it.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Grijesh, first timer!

Comment: Well, how is `list` initialized?  In other words, what is its dynamic type?

Comment: this.list = new ArrayList<List<Thing>>()

Comment: Then that's why it doesn't work.  It isn't a `Rows`, so you can't cast it to a `Rows`.  `B extends A` means that `B` [is an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_a) `A`, but not vice versa.

Comment: Do you know of another way of returning a Rows type within the constrains of the List<List<Thing>> type? Rows has certain behaviors that I need later. I am not allowed to modify the method's return type, but I can change Rows's type.

Comment: why are you using a List within a List? maybe have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle and re-think your solution. There is no need to over-complicate things.

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the feedback, Oliver, I'll try and simplify it further if possible too.

Comment: Some general notes: `implements` is redundant, ArrayList already implements that interface; extending ArrayList or any other library class not specifically designed to be extended is bad practice. You should have designed your own class which *uses* an ArrayList internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rows extends ArrayList<List<Thing>>
```

The above definition says that `Rows` is a *subclass* of `ArrayList<List<Thing>>` (which means it's a specialized version), **not** that `Rows` is the same thing as an `ArrayList<List<Thing>>`.

This means that a `Rows` is a kind of `ArrayList<List<Thing>>` (so upcasting works) but an `ArrayList<List<Thing>>` is not necessarily a `Rows` (so downcasting doesn't work).

If you have an object that you've created as a `new ArrayList<List<Thing>>`, then this is its type and you can't downcast it further. If you want to be able to use it as a `Rows`, you simply need to create it it as a `new Rows`.

(By the way, plural is unconventional for class names.)

Comment: I see it now, nowhere as complex as I thought! Thanks very much, I have changed it and it now works.